# Needed assistance with getting the users location if there is a change in the users position using HTML5 and JS

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I need some help in tracking the user continuously. According to the research I did, the watchPosition function will return the new position if there is a change in user's location. Is that correct? And also where should this snippet be placed, right after the getCurrentPosition function? If not so, do you have any solutions or suggestions how I can achieve continuous tracking.

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
function(position) {
    calculateDistance(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
}, function(err){ 
    console.log(err);
}, {enableHighAccuracy:true, maximumAge:30000, timeout:27000});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct and you don't need to call `getCurrentPosition()` at all as `watchPosition()` does the same thing, only continously.

So call it instead of where you are currently calling `getCurrentPosition()`.

Comment: Glad to have helped although I only confirmed what you already knew!